# Ajuda em exercicio de faculdade

Tags: python, python-3.x

O enunciado é:

> Crie um programa que receba como entrada o valor total de uma dívida
> (número natural maior que zero) e o valor máximo que o devedor pode
> pagar todo mês (número natural maior que zero).
>
> O programa deve exibir o restante da dívida antes e depois de cada
> pagamento mensal até que a dívida zere.
>
> Obs.: quando a dívida é menor do que o máximo que o devedor pode
> pagar, ele pagará exatamente quanto deve, jamais pagará um valor
> superior.
>
> Na primeira linha um valor natural maior que zero indicando o valor da
> dívida; na segunda linha o valor máximo que o devedor pode pagar por
> mês (novamente um valor natural maior que zero).
>
> O valor da dívida restante antes do pagamento mensal e o valor da
> dívida restante após o pagamento mensal, conforme o formato nos
> exemplos. Repetir enquanto a dívida não zerar.
>
> Entrada:
>
> ```
> 150
> 50
> ```
>
> Saída:
>
> ```
> (antes) 150
> (depois) 100
> (antes) 100
> (depois) 50
> (antes) 50
> (depois) 0
> ```

Meu código:

```
maximo = int(input())
minimo = int(input())
count = maximo
cont_1 = minimo
while maximo > minimo:
  maximo -= minimo
  print('(antes) {}'.format(maximo))
  print('(depois) {}'.format(cont_1))
```

Não sei onde estou errando no referido código.

Comment: Coloca uma pergunta mais descritiva pra ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida

Comment: Danilo, quando uma resposta resolver o seu problema e não lhe restar mais nenhuma dúvida, considere a marcar como como correta/aceita clicando no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Estive vendo o seu histórico de perguntas e todas possuem respostas e continuam em aberto.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro comece dando os nomes corretos para as variáveis. Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

Em nenhum momento foi mencionado o valor mínimo, somente o valor máximo a ser pago e o valor da dívida, então temos apenas:

```
divida = int(input())
maximo = int(input())
```

Exatamente nesta ordem, que é o que o enunciado diz.

Depois no loop você deve verificar se a dívida não está zerada (ou seja, se `divida > 0`).

E dentro do `while` você desconta o valor da dívida, se atentando para o caso em que ela é menor ou igual ao valor a ser pago (pois neste caso ela deve ser zerada)

```
while divida > 0: # enquanto ainda deve algo
    print("(antes) {}".format(divida))
    if divida <= maximo: # zerar a dívida 
        divida = 0
    else: # descontar o valor máximo do valor da dívida 
        divida -= maximo
    print("(depois) {}".format(divida))
```

Repare que os prints relativos a "antes" e "depois" são feitos... antes e depois de descontar o valor :-)

[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/FEltLJ) o código rodando.

Comment: eu pensei que tinha que usar um contador pra subir o print antes da divida

Comment: @DaniloBalbo Não precisa de contador, já que a única condição para continuar o loop é que o valor da dívida seja maior que zero: "*Repetir enquanto a dívida não zerar.*"

Comment: Eu estou com muita duvida nessa parte da faculdade de while e for, não entra na minha cabeça

Comment: As estruturas `while` e `for` são `bastante` utilizadas por `quaisquer` linguagens de programação. Por isso, aconselho estuda-las bastante, não só suas formas `básicas`, mas também, como no caso do `Python`, suas `diversas` variantes. Estas variantes são muito empregadas em [List Comprehesion](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/459254/d%C3%A1-para-fazer-o-for-em-1-linha).

Answer (score 1):

Nesta questão você tem que prestar atenção em duas situações: 1º verificar o `resto da divisão` entre a dívida e o valor máximo da parcela e 2º verificar o `total` de parcelas.

Perceba que, em algumas situações, o resto da divisão entre a dívida e o valor máximo da parcela `será igual a "0"`, o que significa dizer que todas as parcelas terão o mesmo valor.

Exemplo 1:

```
divida = 100
valor_maximo_parcela = 10
```

Nesta situação todas as parcelas terão o valor de `10`.

Em outras situações, o resto da divisão entre a dívida e valor máximo da parcela será `diferente de "0"`. O que significa dizer que a última parcela terá valor compreendido entre `"0"` e o valor `"maximo_parcela"`.

Exemplo 2:

```
divida = 100
valor_maximo_parcela = 32
```

Nesta situação o valor da última parcela será diferente das anteriores

Diante desta situação podemos dizer que para pagar um dívida de 100, com o valor máximo de cada parcela igual à 32, seria necessário `4` parcelas. Pois a divisão realizada aqui não seria a divisão real `"/"` e sim a divisão inteira `"//"`. Neste caso, teríamos três parcelas de 32 e uma parcela (a última) de 4.

Diante de tais observações já abordadas, desenvolvi o seguinte algoritmo.

```
# Capturando e tratando o valor da dívida:
while True:
    try:
        divida = int(input('Valor total da dívida: '))
        if divida <= 0:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores maiores que "0"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')

# Capturando e tratando o maior valor por parcela mensal:
while True:
    try:
        valor_parcela = int(input('Maior valor por parcela mensal: '))
        if valor_parcela <= 0:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores maiores que "0"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')

# Realizando os cálculos:
resto = divida % valor_parcela

if resto == 0:
    parcela = (divida // valor_parcela)
else:
    parcela = ((divida // valor_parcela) + 1)


# Realizando cálculos finais e exibindo resultados:
print()
ordem = 0
while divida > 0:
    ordem += 1
    print(f'\033[32mDívida antes do pagamento da {ordem}º parcela: {divida}')
    divida = (divida - valor_parcela)
    if divida >= parcela:
        print(f'Dívida após o pagamento da {ordem}ª parcela é: {divida}')
    elif 0 < divida < parcela:
        print(f'Dívia após o pagamento da {ordem}ª parcela é: {divida}')
print(f'Dívida após o pagamento da última parcela é: 0\033[m')
```

Veja o funcionamento do algoritmo no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/join/fzytyybi-solkarped)

Note que este algoritmo também realiza um tratamento dos valores recebidos pelos inputs e só deixa avançar se os valores forem inteiros e maiores do que zero.